# How to fix an Updating watchkit app that hangs on loading screen?

Tags: ios, xamarin, watchkit, apple-watch

Start situation:

Lets say we have two iOS app versions that both include a watchkit app. Both apps are Ad-Hoc builds with inhouse PP. lets label theb Version 1 and 2. When I install version 1, the app works just fine, the watch works as expected. Then I delete version 1 and install version 2. The same result, beautifully working apps both on the iPhone and the apple watch.

The Problem:
Now lets install version 1 and override it with version 2. The app installs succesfully on the iPhone and the watch. The iphone app launches, the Watch app hangs on the Loading spinner!!

The app is build uisng Xamarin 5.7, I don't know if this is part of the problem but i think it is important to mention.

iOS version: 9.2
Watch os: 2.1
XCode: 7.2.1
Xamarin: 5.7

log:

```
Mar  7 17:25:08 Joses-iPhone companionappd[124] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m __51-[SPCompanionAppServer sendToRemoteInterface:call:]_block_invoke:1009> Semaphore timed out! Please file a radar.
Mar  7 17:25:18 Joses-iPhone companionappd[124] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m __51-[SPCompanionAppServer sendToRemoteInterface:call:]_block_invoke:1009> Semaphore timed out! Please file a radar.
Mar  7 17:25:19 Joses-iPhone companionappd[124] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPApplicationManager.m __56-[SPApplicationManager beginUsingPlugin:withCompletion:]_block_invoke285:426> * * * After 10.0 secs, beginUsing: hasn't called us back for plugin with beginUsingInstanceUUID <__NSConcreteUUID 0x145657170> 9AF88A58-1709-4934-A478-831D908FA0D6
Mar  7 17:25:19 Joses-iPhone companionappd[124] <Notice>: (Warn ) WatchKit: <SPApplicationManager.m __83-[SPApplicationManager getOrBeginActivePlugInForApplication:setupBlock:completion:]_block_invoke_2338:503> Unable to start plugin xx.xx.xx.watchkitextension 0x14556e0c0 with identifier xx.xx.xx.watchkitapp (Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=15 "PKPlugin beginUsing: never called back" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=PKPlugin beginUsing: never called back})
Mar  7 17:25:19 Joses-iPhone companionappd[124] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m __51-[SPCompanionAppServer sendToRemoteInterface:call:]_block_invoke615:998> activePlugInForIdentifier: returned nil for application xx.xx.xx.watchkitapp
Mar  7 17:25:28 Joses-iPhone companionappd[124] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m __51-[SPCompanionAppServer sendToRemoteInterface:call:]_block_invoke:1009> Semaphore timed out! Please file a radar.
```

After restarting the iPhone the watchkitapp starts without any ptoblems!